# How to find a list of all dairy farms in the New York State?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I work for Cap Vert Energie, a French company which has a branch in New York. Our activity consists in developing photovoltaic installations. Thus, we search for infrastructures in the New York and Massachusetts states on which we can put solar panels. More precisely, we look for Dairy farms, sheep farmers and goat farmers so we can maybe put solar panels on their roofs.

Does [data.gov](https://www.data.gov/) or other sites have this kind of data?

Comment: Might be better to look at New York state government's site: corporate dairy farms would be registered.

Answer (score 2):

Not the solution you seek, but pieces you can roll your own solution out of:

[New York Division of Milk Control and Dairy Services](https://www.agriculture.ny.gov/DI/DIHome.html) releases annual reports that have part of this data.

Example: [2016 Report](https://www.agriculture.ny.gov/DI/NYSAnnStat2016.pdf); it doesn't have a list with contact information, but has markers like number of farms per county, etc., that can provide the foundation to what you are seeking.

[USDA Northeast Marketing Area - Federal Order 1 Plant Handlers List](http://www.fmmone.com/Plants_Handlers_list.htm) has some [more](http://www.fmmone.com/Maps/NEZoneDiffMap.pdf) [data](http://www.fmmone.com/Plant_List/Non_Pool.pdf) that you can build atop/glean from.